# What does <T> represent in C# syntax?

Tags: c#

What does the following syntax mean? Specifically the <> braces? (Can't seem to google it)

```
public T Execute<T>(RestRequest request) where T : new()
{ .... }
```

Here's what I understand;

`public` = the visibility of the function.

`T` = the return type (probably defined somewhere else in code)

`(RestRequest request)` = the function parameter list. `request` is the lone parameter

The remaining bits - `Execute<T> ... where T : new()` is strange and new to me.

Possibly related, but what does the following actually return? (as in; does it return a function or an object or a reference to something?)

```
return Execute<Call>(request);
```

Both the code snippets were taken from the RestSharp documentation wiki example code - https://github.com/restsharp/RestSharp/wiki/Recommended-Usage

Comment: That syntax introduces generic type parameters. See [Generics (C#  Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/512aeb7t.aspx)

Comment: Top google search results for `C# <T>` point to generics. Just interesting - what exactly you have searched?

Comment: I tried searching for "public T Execute<T>" and "Execute<T>". Didn't really help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The remaining bits - `Execute<T> ... where T : new()` is strange and new to me.

So, `Execute` is method name. `<T>` is generic parameter `T` ([See Generics (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/512aeb7t.aspx)) and `where T : new()` is generic constraint, which requires `T` to have parameterless constructor.

> Possibly related, but what does the following actually return? (as in; does it return a function or an object or a reference to something?)
>
> `return Execute<Call>(request);`

Because `Execute<T>` returns `T` and you call is with `T = Call` this one will return `Call` class instance (or possible `null` if only `Call` is `class`, not `struct`).

Comment: Don't exactly have a full understanding of the code, but this answer gives me enough to puzzle the rest on my own. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 2):

> `T` = the return type (probably defined somewhere else in code)

Actually it is defined between the `<>`. When you go to call this function you put your own type in the brackets, so in your `return Execute<Call>(request);`  turns in to the function signature `public Call Execute(RestRequest request);`

The `where T : new()` is a limitation on what you can put inside the brackets, what you are declaring is whatever is going to be passed in as `T` must implment a default constructor that is public (that is what `new()` means.

Answer (score 0):

Here  represents type of your collection it could be predefined datatype or user defined datatype like any class

Answer (score 0):

Here it is a constraint on the generic parameter. Generic classes and methods combine reusability, type safety and efficiency. The new constraint specifies that any type argument in a generic class declaration must have a public parameterless constructor. To use the new constraint, the type cannot be abstract.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0x6a29h6.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sd2w2ew5.aspx